# Storing JSON array in SQL table in flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I want to store the JSON array returned after sending post request to a server into a SQL table, but can't get a relevant example or information to do so on net.

The JSON returned is:

```
"subject": [
        {
            "subject_name": "Programming and Problem Solving",
            "subject_desc": "99",
            "internship": "0",
            "info": "Programming and Problem Solving using Python",
            "no_units": "6",
            "is_deleted": "0",
            
        },
        {
            
            "subject_name": "Basic Electrical Engineering",
            "subject_desc": "99",
            "internship": "0",
            "info": "",
            "no_units": "100",
            "is_deleted": "0",
        },
        {
            "subject_name": "Engineering Mathematics II",
            "subject_desc": "99",
            "internship": "0",
            "info": "",
            "no_units": "6",
            "is_deleted": "0",
        },
        {
            "subject_name": "Engineering Graphics",
            "subject_desc": "99",
            "internship": "0",
            "info": "",
            "no_units": "6",
            "is_deleted": "0",
        }
    ],
```

The columns in table should be the key from JSON.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jsonDecode() from the built-in dart:convert library to convert the JSON to a Map<String, dynamic>.

If you are using sqFlite or a similar database, your code will look similar to this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> decodedData = jsonDecode(jsonObject);

for(Map<String, dynamic> subjectMap in decodedData['subject']){
  sqFliteDatabase.insert('table_subject', subjectMap);
}
```

I hope this helps.